# re-read-init-file action in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, readline

I have the following in my `.inputrc` file:

```
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

According to the *readline* man page. this should mean that pressing Ctrl+X, Ctrl+R should reread my `.inputrc` file. This is what happens insofar as any *additional* bindings are picked up, but if I remove a binding and then trigger the *re-read-init-file* action with that key combination, the key binding I've just removed from `.inputrc` still operates in Bash. Is this intentional behaviour? If so, is there a way to avoid it, and actually reset all bindings whilst doing *re-read-init-file*?

Comment: Yes it is intentional. The commands in the `.inputrc` are executed (subject to the conditional commands of course). This augments the current bindings rather than replaces them. There is no explicit command to reset all the bindings and variables, but you could create a script to do this.

Comment: @icarus Thanks. How would I create such a script? If you post your comments as an answer and add that, happy to accept it.

Comment: The basic idea is to use `bind -p > ~/bash_default_bindings` and then use `bind -f ~/.bash_default_bindings`, possibly after looping over all the current bindings and using `bind -r` to remove them. It is made more complicated by the keymaps, which require another loop to handle them.

Comment: @icarus Thanks, makes sense.